# precision of number held in a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
import os

reader=open('try.txt', 'r')
data=reader.read()
reader.close()

x=0.0
y=0.0
z=0.0

def xcoord():
    global x
    global y
    global z
    while x<=1.0:
        mypath1='C:\\Users\\Rebecca\\Documents\\PhD\\Learnpython\\X' + str(x)
        os.makedirs(mypath1)
        ycoord()
        x+=0.01
        y=0.0
        z=0.0

def ycoord():
    global x
    global y
    global z
    while y<=1.0:
        mypath2='C:\\Users\\Rebecca\\Documents\\PhD\\Learnpython\\X' + str(x) + '\\Y' + str(y)
        os.makedirs(mypath2)
        zcoord()
        y+=0.01
        z=0.0

def zcoord():
    global z
    while z<=1.0:
        writer=open('C:\\Users\\Rebecca\\Documents\\PhD\\Learnpython\\X' + str(x) + '\\Y' + str(y) + '\\X' + str(x) + 'Y' + str(y) + 'Z' + str(z) + '.dat', 'a')
        writer.write(data)
        print('interstitial Ce' + ' %.2f' % x + ' %.2f' % y + ' %.2f' % z + ' fix', file=writer)
        print('centre' + ' %.2f' % x + ' %.2f' % y + ' %.2f' % z, file=writer)
        print('size 14 28', file=writer)
        print('dump1 inter' + '%.2f' % x + '%.2f' % y +'%.2f' % z + '.dat', file=writer)
        print('output xyz ' + '%.2f' % x + '%.2f' % y + '%.2f' % z + '.xyz', file=writer)
        writer.close()
        z+=0.01

xcoord()
```

**[N.B. I am aware using global variables in this way is not ideal but it this is  currently the only way I can get my head round the  code and get it to do what I want....]**

When this is executed, the values of x, y and z increase as required, but (only sometimes) output value has several decimal places.

How do I alter the setting such that x, y and z are only ever to 2 decimal places?

Any help would be appreciated - cheers

Comment: The value 0.1 cannot be exactly represented in base 2. Read this: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `round(n, 2)`? This will display only two numbers after the decimal point. However, keep in mind that this only makes it appear up to two numbers, the real representation will still be much larger. This is because some numbers cannot be represented exactly using floating-point numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.

Question (which may seem obvious to you but isn't so to me so please be patient) though:

Lets say I print the value of x to a text file, such that it only shows to 2dp.
This text file is then used as an input into a fortran program:
Does the fortran program read the value to 2dp (as seen on screen) or as the full value?

Comment: It can only use the data you give it, so 2dp.  But you should post this as a new queetion, not as an answer (you'll get better answers too)